# pass RoteData to view by mvc model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routedata

I'm currently learning asp.net core, so tried to add RouteData to my mvc model and pass it to view, however when I count the number of Data values ( `@Model.Data.Count` ) it returns 0. I don't want to use ViewBag or `@ViewContext.RouteData.Values[key]` in my view code.

mvc route

```
app.UseMvc(route =>
        {
            route.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}/{*catchall}");
        });
```

my action method

```
public ViewResult List(string id)
    {
        var r = new Result
        {
            Controller = nameof(HomeController),
            Action = nameof(List),
        };

        // var catch=RouteData.Values["catchall"]; this line is working fine
        r.Data["id"] = id ?? "<no value>";
        r.Data["catchall"] = RouteData.Values["catchall"];
        //when I checked r.Data.count it returns 0 even in here
        return View("Result", r);
    }
```

and my view

```
@model Result
.
.
@foreach (var key in Model.Data.Keys)
    {
        <tr><th>@key :</th><td>@Model.Data[key]</td></tr>
    }
```

Comment: What's the full definition of `Result`?

Comment: one of them is my model. containing 2 strings and an IDictionary<string,object>. another one is just a view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need your own `Dictionary` as long as you have `ViewData` property, but you should cast your `object` every time you get it like this:

```
public ViewResult List(string id)
    {
        var r = new Result
        {
            Controller = nameof(HomeController),
            Action = nameof(List),
        };

        ViewData["id"] = id ?? "<no value>";
        ViewData["catchall"] = RouteData.Values["catchall"];

        return View("Result", r);
    }
```

On your View:

```
<tr><th>id :</th><td>@(int)ViewData["id"]</td></tr>
```

I suppose you have the same problem - you should cast value to get it from `object`. You get `string` property becouse every object has `.ToSting()` method.